# Scrolling event listener not working on sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a problem working with `addEventListener` so I made very simple script outside my code to see the problem, it is still there on this small script.

However if I use same script and pass `click` listener instead of scroll, it works.

```js
const section2 = document.querySelector("#section2")

console.log(section2)

section2.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log("clicked")
})

section2.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
  console.log("scrolling")
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="section1">
    section
  </section>
    <section id="section2">
    section 2
  </section>
    <section id="section3">
    section 3
  </section>
    <section id="section4">
    section 4
  </section>
    <section id="section5">
    section 5
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: `section2` won't fire a scroll event as it is not scrollable. Try adding content which overflows `section2`.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, `section2` is never scrolling, what exactly are you trying to listen for?

Comment: I just want to know that I am scrolling over this section of my code.

Comment: Closest you can go is by using mouse over listener.

Comment: When you say "scrolling over" do you mean when the element is in the middle of the page? or is visible on the page? or is within X amount of the top/middle/bottom of the page? All these are possible with a window scroll event listener and some calculations, but you will need to explain exactly what you want before we can help.